# How to find select result in stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select count(*) into dup_row_count from tablea ;

if dup_row_count is not null then
  total_row_count :=1;
else
  total_row_count :=2;
end if;
```

In above query if there is no data present in select statement then if else condition not working.

Please can you help me in how to find select query gives any result or not so that on that basis I can change my if else condition.  (Oracle database - stored procedure)

Answer (score 3):

A `COUNT(*)` will never return NULL.

```
select count(*) 
  into dup_row_count 
  from tablea ;
```

will return 0 if there are no rows in the table.  So you'd want your IF statement to be something like

```
if dup_row_count > 0 then
  total_row_count :=1;
else
  total_row_count :=2;
end if;
```

If all you care about is whether there are any rows, however, it would potentially be more efficient to do something like

```
select count(*) 
  into dup_row_count 
  from tablea 
 where rownum < 2;
```

so that the database can stop counting rows once it finds the first one.

Comment: Elaborating on your `where rownum < 2` example, I think the following should eliminate the need for the `if` statement: `select 2 - count(*) into total_row_count from tablea where rownum < 2;`, unless, of course, `dup_row_count` is needed elsewhere as well as for calculating `total_row_count`.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the SQL as below

```
select decode(count(*),0,2,1) 
  into dup_row_count 
  from tablea ;
```

In this case you do not need the `if... else` conditions. This is handled by the decode function.